# Организация видеосвязи на сайте. NodeJs + PHP + WEBRtc

Tags: php, node.js, webrtc

Возникла задача сделать сайт, на котором будет около 1 000 страниц. И на каждой странице должна быть возможность позвонить по видеосвязи оператору, просто Peer-to-Peer.

Сайт я хочу сделать на какой-нибудь обычной CMS, типа Wordpress. Связь реализовать через WEBRtc на NodeJS.

Делать сайт на 1000 страниц на nodeJS считаю бессмысленным из-за отсутствия простых CMS.

Реализацию WEBRtc на php не нашел.

Подскажите, можно ли как-то php(Nginx, Apache) и nodeJS поженить между собой на одной странице? И вообще в ту ли сторону я копаю?

Comment: Тут WP лишнее, как по мне. back - php (api), nodejs - для webrtc (аля signalling-server)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно через Node.js коннектить пиры. Все пользователи у которых есть возможность совершить/принять связь, должны быть приконекченны к сокету на Node.js, и при вызовах посылать экшены другому юзеру с данными пира (ice candidates, sdp offer). И после, отправлять обратно ответные данные. И нужно подумать о реконнекте, как я понял, это не SPA, а значит при переходе на другую страничку звонок будет сбрасываться.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-answer).